# rails4 / emails and special characters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, encoding, ruby-on-rails-4

On some app' setup
Everything works fine within the email, in the body

There is a problem with the subject of this email, containing special characters,
which would output the following for exemple in the mailboxes :

```
a Ã©tÃ© validÃ©e !
```

Searching around, I ended up with the following that works :

```
s = ("...a été validée !...").encode!("ISO-8859-15")
m = mail(to: email, subject: s)
```

But I guess that it is just a setup thing that would make everything works fine
Has anyone any experience about it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this in your application.rb?

`config.action_mailer.default_charset = "iso-8859-15"`

I'm using the default (utf-8) and accents work just fine, so you may want to see if there's something else that's botching up your data.

UPDATE: since this is only an issue with your subject, I think you may be able to fix this by adding this to the top of your source file that contains that subject line:

`# encoding: UTF-8`

Please try that out and let me know.

Comment: that's the point, I wonder why within the body everything is okay, but the subject won't render in the correct encoding. I guess if I put the default charset to iso-8859-15, I'm might end up with other problems. Going to try it though

Comment: Can you check the `Content-Type:` header value in your received email before doing this? Is it utf-8 or iso-8859-15?